# Function definition in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I'm beginning to learn Haskell with "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" and I've made a strange mistake, which I can't find the reason for.

Here is the code I typed:

```
let xs = [if x < 3 then "bang" else "boom" | x <- xs]
```

And the the text of the error in GHCi:

```
No instance for (Num [Char])
arising from the literal `3'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
In the second argument of `(<)', namely `(3)'
In the expression: x < (3)
In the expression: if x < (3) then "bang" else "boom"
```

But when I type:

```
let boom xs = [if x < 3 then "bang" else "boom" | x <- xs]
```

which is the example of the book, I don't have any problem.

Could someone explain my mistake?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers; they complement each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to give the expression a type.

```
xs = [if x < 3 then "bang" else "boom" | x <- xs]
```

So `xs` is a list, we don't know yet what type its elements have, so let's look at that next. The list elements are

```
if x < 3 then "bang" else "boom"
```

which is an expression of type `String` (aka `[Char]`).

So `xs :: [String]`. Since the `x` from the expression describing the list elements is taken from the list `xs` itself, it is a `String` too, and is used in the comparison

```
if x < 3
```

Now, `3` is an integer literal, thus it is polymorphic and has type

```
3 :: Num a => a
```

So from the expression `x < 3`, we have

- a `Num` constraint from the literal,
- the type `String` from the fact that `x` is drawn from a list of `String`s.

Thus we need a `Num` instance for `String` to have a well-typed expression.

Usually, there is no `Num` instance for `String` (what would a useful one look like?), so you get a type error.

If `xs` is the argument of a function,

```
boom xs = [if x < 3 then "bang" else "boom" | x <- xs]
```

there is no reason why the type of `x` should be `String`, hence that works.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers; they complement each other.

Answer (score 13):

Your definition of `xs` is recursive, that is you're using `xs` inside its own definition. I don't think that's what you intended.

Since you're using `"bang"` and `"boom"` inside the list comprehensions, Haskell knows that `xs` must be a list of strings (because `xs` is equal to the result of the list comprehension). Further you say that `x` is an element of `xs` (`x <- xs`), so `x` must be a String (a.k.a. `[Char]`). However you do `x < 3`, which implies that `x` is a number. The error message means "a String is not a number".

Comment: Darn, beat me by a few seconds.. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
let xs = ...
```

means xs equals a list of "bang"s and/or "boom"s, but the condition states that those elements should be tested for <3, which is usually done with numbers, not strings.

```
let boom xs =...
```

equates the function 'boom' with the right hand side of the equation, where the parameter 'xs' is the list from which the elements to be tested for <3 are drawn.